# UIImageView tags, how can i find which view is on top?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

is there any easy way to check if one UIImageView is on another one ? My views has tags, and they cover each other, they moves, the main problem is
that i wanna hide at all view, if it's not on top, how can i check which one view is on top ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`CGRectIntersectsRect` is going to return true if any part of rect1 lies inside of rect2.

**Example:**

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1.frame, rect2.frame)) {
 //rect1 is lies inside rect 2
}
```